# Как реализовать вывод 404 ошибки на PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

В общем пробую стандартный вариант, в .htaccess пишу

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://.site.ru/404.php
```

и в коде к несуществующей странице ставлю функцию для установки ответа http_response_code(404);
Но в этом случае всегда редиректит на эту страницу - 404.php . То есть URL получается меняется тоже. Я видел на многих сайтах, что если вводишь несуществующий URL, то он не менятеся, а на нем же подгружается шаблон 404 страницы.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: В Laravel, например, как return redirect("https: //my.address.com/bar", 404)

Comment: а куда ведет my.address.com/bar ?

Comment: Вы можете проставить в вашем веб-сервере обработку 404 ответа от низлежащего сайта и отдавать [404 страницу](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04) без редиректа.